# Google Cloud OCR returning cyrillic characters

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I need to replace M and K in an OCR result. Sometimes, however, google-vision recognizes it as cyrillic K or M.

To prevent this, I tried to limit language to english.

```
response = client.text_detection(image=open(img, 'rb'), image_context={"language_hints": ["en"]})
```

However, I'm not sure if I done it right... cyrillic alphabet keeps popping up and I'm afraid it would use another alphabet.

Is there a way to force only english alphabet?

```
['1.3M/1.2M', '663.8K/1.5M']
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem but it's the C and Os which are returned as Cyrillic. Did you event find out a solution for your problem?

Comment: Same problem here...